# Changing TextInputLayout's Hint value as the user types in it

Tags: java, android

[image: TextInputEditText]

Here is my `TextInputEditText` inside `TextInputLayout`. The hint you can see is set on `TextInputLayout`.

The user must write **255 characters** otherwise the post is not valid.

I want the digit **255** to decrease as the user types and when reached to 0, the hint should be blank.

Here is my code :

`private int charactersLeft = 256;` is declared outside `onCreate` method.

And this code is inside `onCreate` method :

```
final TextInputLayout postTextInputBase = findViewById(R.id.post_text_input_base);

final TextInputEditText postTextInput = findViewById(R.id.post_text_input);

postTextInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (charactersLeft == 0) {
            postTextInputBase.setHint(null);
        } else {
            postTextInputBase.setHint((charactersLeft - 1) + " characters left");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

I also tried to set `charactersLeft` to `characterLeft -= 1` but, the `java` won't allow me to do that.

Then, how do I do this ?

Comment: If you check the TextInputLayout class there is already a counter field and it will be visible if you set setCounterEnabled(true) in case you want to show counter

Comment: Thank you very much @Dr. aNdRo, it worked ! But what I want to do is show "characters left" too.

Comment: You can add a textview and count the edit text characters manually and update that textview from the text Watcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Works with your existing code.

```
int charactersLeft = 256;
final TextInputLayout postTextInputBase = findViewById(R.id.post_text_input_base);
final TextInputEditText postTextInput = findViewById(R.id.post_text_input);

postTextInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {           
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if (s.length() == 0) {
                postTextInputBase.setHint(null);
            }else {
                postTextInputBase.setHint((charactersLeft - s.length()) + " characters left");
            }
        }
    });
```

and Add  `android:maxLength="256"` to your `TextInputEditText`

Comment: Simple but elegant solution :)

Comment: Simplest solution which could work with my existing code ! Thanks a lot @Anisuzzaman Babla !

Answer (score 4):

Use  [**`app:counterEnabled="true"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout#setCounterEnabled(boolean))

- Whether the character counter functionality is enabled or not in this layout.

Also use [**`app:counterMaxLength="250"`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setCounterMaxLength(int))

- Sets the max length to display at the character counter.

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/post_text_input_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="250">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/post_text_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="UserName" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

## EDIT

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputLayout postTextInputBase;
    EditText postTextInputEditText;

    int textLength = 9;
    int len = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        postTextInputBase = findViewById(R.id.post_text_input_base);

        postTextInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.post_text_input);

        postTextInputBase.setHint(textLength + " characters left");

        postTextInputEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // first check your EditText is empty or not
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(postTextInputEditText.getText().toString())) {

                    int len = postTextInputEditText.getText().toString().length();
                    // than check that editText text length is less than max length or not
                    // for test case i have set max length 10
                    if (len < 9) {
                        // if length of text is less than max length than use minus one from max length and set error in your text input layout
                        textLength--;
                    } else {
                        textLength++;
                        
                    }
                    
                    postTextInputBase.setHint(textLength + " characters left");
                } else {
                    textLength = 9;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

              if(postTextInputEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                  textLength = 9;
                  postTextInputBase.setHint(textLength + " characters left");
              }
            }
        });


    }


}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

## EDIT 2 If you need set hint than use this

```
postTextInputBase.setHint(textLength + " characters left");
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

> **NOTE**  Don't forgot to set **`android:maxLength="10"`** in edittext

Comment: This doesn't suffice his UI. He wants to show counter at hint

Comment: Thank you very much @Nilesh Rathod, this works ! But what I want to do is show "characters left" too.

Comment: @DetainedDeveloper please wait i will update my answer

Comment: Sure, @NileshRathod

Comment: You are re using the error field :D, Yes that can be a way if that works for him

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO yes but both are same any way thanks i have updated the answer

Comment: @AnisuzzamanBabla not working  means my friend can u explain more

Comment: When i pasted  3 characters it minuses 1. @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: @AnisuzzamanBabla thanks found the mistake have a look updated answer

Comment: @NileshRathod Still same problem exists.

Comment: @NileshRathod It doesn't solved the issues with copy/paste and delete multiple character at a time my friend.

Comment: @NileshRathod Now it minuses 2 every time I type a character.

Comment: After some modifications this works, too. Thank you for taking your time for this @NileshRathod !!! I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it programatically using `setOnKeyListener` on the edit text.

```
TextInputLayout postTextInputBase = findViewById(R.id.post_text_input_base);
TextInputEditText postTextInput = findViewById(R.id.post_text_input);
postTextInput.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
        // Do other things needed
        postTextInputBase.setHint("Characters left: " + (256 - postTextInput.getText().length()));
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Tosin John ! This also works ! I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To change Hint text only you can just change it on focus change.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
                editText.setHint("Enter name");
            else
                editText.setHint("Name");
        }
    });
```